# Money Demand on the 60's and 70's

Tags: interest-rate, money-supply

i just maked a model about the money demand in USA on the between 1962 and 1979 and i just found that the money demand was positively influenced by the interest rate. I know i'm not given any details but i would like to know what happened between thoose years, that can explain why the money demand was positively correlated with the interest rate thoose years. What happened in the US during thoose years?

Comment: Did you really find it was positively influenced? Or did you just find it was correlated? i.e. how did you establish causality?